# Custom MarkerStyle in MS Chart Control

Tags: c#, vb.net, mschart

How can I use alphabets as `MarkerStyle` in MS Chart control using VB.Net? The defaults (square, triangle, circle, etc.) are insufficient.

```
Select Case UCase(strCharSymbol)
    Case "+"
        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Cross
    Case "0", "O"
        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
    Case "*"
        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star10
    Case "^"
        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle
    Case "#"
        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square
    Case Else
        .MarkerStyle = MYCUSTOMMARKER(strCharSymbol)
End Select
```

Comment: Show some code what you have tried, before you get down votes :)

Comment: I have added code for `MarkerStyle` selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MarkerStyle`are fixed and cannot be customized. But still you can use the `MarkerImage` property to set an image as an marker.

To achieve your goal, you have to create alphabet images and give their path in the `MarkerImage` property. In your code, do the below change.

```
Case Else
    .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
    .MarkerImage = 'Path of the image
```